# Let $f:\Bbb{R^\times}\to\Bbb{R^\times}$ be an isomorphism. Show that $f$ takes $\Bbb R^{>0}$ to $\Bbb R^{>0}$, and $\Bbb R^{<0}$ to $\Bbb R^{<0}$.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^\times}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^\times}$ be an isomorphism. Show that $f$ takes positive numbers to positive numbers and negative to negative.

If $f$ is an isomorphism, then it's bijective and that $f(g_1g_2)=f(g_1)f(g_2)$.

I think that $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R^\times}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^\times}$ is also an isomorphism means I only have to show $f$ takes positive numbers to positive numbers, but I'm not exactly sure why. Thanks for the help.

---

Note: $\mathbb R^\times$ is the multiplicative group of non-zero real numbers.

Comment: Could you let us know what you mean by $\mathbb R*$.  Is that the multiplicative group on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$?  Or the multiplicative group on $\mathbb R^+$, the positive real numbers?  In any case, please state explicitly what group you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, $R^*$ means $R$ with respect to multiplication.

Comment: $\mathbb R^\times$ is a better notation for the non-zero reals with multiplication.

Comment: If I may ask, why am I being downvoted? Is my question off topic or is it because my question wasn't asked properly?

Comment: I have decided to cast my vote for the reopening of this question. There are full definitions given, and the OP has come up with a possible approach to the question by themselves. This question would be better off if the OP indicated which class this was from or their background, but obviously it is too late to bring the OP back.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$ is positive, $f(x)=f(\sqrt x)^2>0$, $f(1)=1$ since $f((-1)(-1))=f(1)=f(-1)^2=1$ we deduce that $f(-1)=-1$ since $f$ is injective, if $x>0, f(-x)=f(-1)f(x)=-f(x)<0$.

Comment: I'm not sure why you said $f(-1)=-1$. If you use specific numbers like that, is there loss of generality?

Comment: I show that $f(-1)=-1$ to prove that if $x>0, f(-x)=f((-1)x)=f(-1)f(x)=-f(x)$ since I know already that $f(x)>0$ if $x>0$ I deduce that $f(-x)<0$.

Comment: Is there any way I can use $f^{-1}$? I get your way but I don't quite get how I can use this fact.

Comment: I use that $f$ is bijective to show that $f(-1)=-1$ since $f(-1)^2=1$, $f(-1)=-1$ or $f(-1)=1$, but $f(-1)\neq f(1)=1$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.